Why isn't UDP port 443 accepting connections when iptables rules are set?
Why isn't UDP port 443 accepting connections when iptables rules are set?
Environment

Operating System: Linux 6.8.0-47-generic #47-Ubuntu, aarch64
Cloud VM: Yes (Hetzner)

Current Setup
I'm trying to set up UDP communication on port 443, but I'm encountering issues despite having configured the firewall rules.
Steps Taken

Added firewall rules:
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
sudo netfilter-persistent save


Current iptables rules:
# IPv4 rules
iptables -L -v -n | grep 443
35318 4093K f2b-nginx-limit-req  6    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
210K   25M f2b-nginx-php-accessrules  6    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
209K   25M f2b-wordpress  6    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
209K   25M f2b-nginx-bad-request  6    --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
302 88281 ACCEPT     17   --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:443

# IPv6 rules
ip6tables -L -v -n | grep 443
61618 9650K f2b-wordpress  6    --  *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 multiport dports 80,443
61600 9649K f2b-nginx-bad-request  6    --  *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 multiport dports 80,443
61600 9649K f2b-nginx-php-accessrules  6    --  *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 multiport dports 80,443
1467  316K ACCEPT     17   --  *      *       ::/0                 ::/0                 udp dpt:443


Port scan results:
sudo nmap -sU -p 443 <server-ip>
Starting Nmap 7.94SVN ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-10-26 20:14 CEST
Nmap scan report for <server-ip>
Host is up (0.0027s latency).

PORT      STATE          SERVICE
443/udp   open|filtered  https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.49 seconds


Attempted netcat test:

Server side:
sudo nc -lu 443


Client side:
echo 'test' | nc -u <server-ip> 443





Issue
No traffic is getting through to the listening netcat process despite the port showing as "open|filtered" in nmap scan.
Questions

Why might the port show as "open|filtered" rather than definitively "open"?
What additional configurations might I need to get UDP traffic flowing through port 443?
Are there any diagnostic steps I should take to identify where the traffic is being blocked?

What I've Already Checked

Firewall rules are in place and saved for both IPv4 and IPv6
Port is not blocked according to nmap
Basic connectivity exists between client and server
Hetzner cloud firewall is configured to allow port 443 UDP
fail2ban has multiple rules for ports 80,443 but these appear to be for TCP (nginx-related)

Additional Information
If anyone needs more details about my setup or additional debugging information, please let me know.

You've not shown your entire ruleset. You added the rule in the last place and there could be preceding rules prohibiting incoming traffic. There could be rules prohibiting outgoing traffic.

Is the title here a typo? UDP doesn’t have connections.

@PhilipCouling: Thank you for pointing that out! You’re correct; UDP is a connectionless protocol, so technically, it doesn’t have “connections” in the traditional sense. I used the term “listening” to mean that the Nginx server is configured to receive packets on UDP port 443 for QUIC traffic, but you’re absolutely right that it’s not a “connection” in the way TCP operates. Thanks for the catch!

1. Why might the port show as "open|filtered" rather than definitively "open"?
Unlike with TCP, there is no guaranteed answer from an open UDP port. It all depends on the application-level protocol on top of UDP.
If the client side sends out an UDP packet and gets an ICMP port unreachable message back, that is a positive indication that the targeted UDP port is closed: either there is no application receiving packets in that port, or a firewall emulates a closed port.
But if the client gets no response at all, the packet might be received by a server-side application and ignored because it did not correspond to the expected format and the application is not designed to send error message packets back; or it might be because a firewall dropped the packet. Hence the open|filtered indication.
2. What additional configurations might I need to get UDP traffic flowing through port 443?
You need to configure your web server software to accept UDP-based forms of the HTTP protocol (i.e. QUIC and HTTP/3).
The Fail2ban rule names f2b-nginx-limit-req, f2b-nginx-php-accessrules and f2b-nginx-bad-request suggest that your web server software is nginx, so please see the nginx documentation page on enabling QUIC and HTTP/3.
Specifically, you'll need at least the listen 443 quic reuseport; directive to activate the QUIC / HTTP/3 support, and this snippet to announce to the HTTP-over-TCP clients that HTTP/3 is available in (UDP) port 443:
location / {
        # required for browsers to direct them to quic port
        add_header Alt-Svc 'h3=":443"; ma=86400';
}

Once the listen 443 quic reuseport; is in effect, your nginx server should be listening for incoming UDP connections. You can verify this with e.g. sudo lsof -i udp:443 on the server system.
As noted by Artem S. Tashkinov, you've only showed us the iptables rules that explicitly mention the port number 443. There could easily be rules that e.g. block all UDP traffic with no regard to port numbers: those won't be visible with ip(6?)tables -L -v -n | grep 443. If such a rule exists before the rule that accepts UDP traffic to port 443, the accepting rule will never be reached because the first matching rule (with an ACCEPT, DROP or another similarly "irrevocable" action) wins.
On the other hand, the packet/data counters for the ip(6?)tables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT rules indicate that both the IPv4 and the IPv6 versions of the rule have matched at least some packets. If the counters keep increasing as you keep testing, it would suggest that the iptables configuration is probably allowing UDP/443 through.
3. Are there any diagnostic steps I should take to identify where the traffic is being blocked?
As mentioned above, you should run
sudo lsof -i udp:443

on the server system to verify that your web server is actually listening for UDP traffic (and not just TCP) on port 443.

Thank you for the suggestion! I ran lsof -i udp:443 as you advised, and it confirmed that my HTTP/3 configuration was already set up correctly. The output shows that Nginx is indeed listening on UDP port 443 for QUIC/HTTP3 connections.
While the web server is already listening on port 443 UDP, the command nc -lu 443 could not work. This is because Nginx’s QUIC setup doesn’t respond to raw UDP packets (like those sent via nc) in the same way it does for QUIC traffic.
